# Fairly simple asp.net async operation on page_load is blocking UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

I have a simple page with a list of events. When a button is clicked, it needs to go to the Attendees page and load the people at that event.

What happens at the moment is that after the button is clicked, the events page stays visible until all of the attendees processing is done and finished and then it shows the result. I want it to show first the event name from the first async call then the progress bar I have on the page can show the list of attendees being built.  If I load the Attendees page directly with an event ID in the querystring it works as desired with the event name being displayed and the progress bar working.

I don't know how to set this up (Async noob) to get the desired result and would appreciate some pointers please!

In events.aspx.cs button click handler:

```
Response.Redirect("Attendees.aspx?eventID=" + eventID, false);
```

Then in Attendees.aspx.cs Page_Load:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        processEvent(); 
        //I've tried this with .Wait() at the end too
    }

    private async Task<bool> processEvent()
    {
        try
        {
            EFEventDetails efEvent = await getEventByIdAsync();
            if (efEvent.responseCode != 200) //only 200 is a valid response code for a found event
            {
                pnl_loadingError.Visible = true;
                pnl_attendees.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //valid event - carry on. Display event name on page.
                lbl_EventHeader.Text = efEvent.data.eventID.ToString() + " - " + efEvent.data.eventName;

                //Now get list of attendees
                List<vmAttendees> res = await getAttendeesAsync();
                if (res.Count > 0)
                {
                    pnl_AttendeeList.Visible = true;
                    rpt_AttendeeList.DataSource = res;
                    rpt_AttendeeList.DataBind();
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            lbl_Result.Text = ex.Message;
            lbl_Result.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            pnl_processResult.Visible = true;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected async Task<EFEventDetails> getEventByIdAsync()
    {
        var eventsForceService = new EventsForceService(_eventsForceRepo);
        return await eventsForceService.getEventByIdAsync(_eventID);
    }

    protected async Task<List<vmAttendees>> getAttendeesAsync()
    {
        var eventsForceService = new EventsForceService(_eventsForceRepo);
        return await eventsForceService.GetAttendeesByEventIDAsync(_eventID);
    }
```

Comment: This does not solve your problem of how to get a working progress bar, but you should read [this article](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx) to see the correct thing to do in `Page_Load` (you need to call `RegisterAsyncTask(processEvent());` and make sure your aspx page has `Async="true"` in it's `Page`  element.) if you just want to wait till the page is fully loaded before showing anything.

Comment: Thanks Scott. If you check my original post you can see I already have the progress bar stuff working just fine if I just directly load the page. I'm using SignalR and event handlers for that. I'm reading the article you posted now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the Attendees loading out of the `Page_Load` Use an APIController and load the data using jQuery Ajax after the page has loaded.

An API Controller example:

```
public class AttendeesController : ApiController
{
    Attendee[] attendees = new Attendee[] 
    { 
        new Attendee { Id = 1, Name = "Mike" }, 
        new Attendee { Id = 2, Name = "Steve" }, 
        new Attendee{ Id = 3, Name = "Diane" } 
    };

    public IEnumerable<Attendee> GetAllAttendees()
    {
        // This is using a premade list of Attendees 
        // but you would get them here and return them

        // Will convert to JSON automatically
        return attendees;
    }
}
```

The AJAX load

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get( "Attendees/GetAllAttendees", function( data ) {
        // Load the data into the page after it returns
        $( ".result" ).html( data );
        alert( "Load was performed." );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm happy doing an ajax call if needed, but I'm trying to avoid it if possible in this case. Is this really the only way of achieving what I'm aiming to do?  Is there no way of doing this with C# code alone?

Comment: If you want a progress bar that updates as things are loaded it will require AJAX of some type.

Comment: Page load is done server side. The page won't load until it is done. So if there is a data call, it will always wait for it. To load the page without waiting on the call, you need to return the page to the client and then load the data with AJAX.

Comment: After experimenting a bit, I now understand better what is going on. Thanks for the other useful links in the comments too, they've been useful reading.  The downside to this method is that I would/will have to recode the logic I've already got in place in the asp.net code behind that binds the returned data to a repeater and formats row colours and properties on binding.